# No result in LINQ query gives Object reference not set to an instance of an object in IF ELSE statement

Tags: linq-to-sql, null, if-statement

I have the following code:

```
        DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();

        var UserInfo = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == TextBox1.Text);

        if (UserInfo.Email != null)
        {
            Label2.Text = "Email is not null";
        }
        else
        {
            Label2.Text = "Email is null";
        }
```

If an e-mail address exists in the table, it successfully prints "Email is not null." However, if there is no matching record, I then receive an Object reference not set to an instance of an object error for Line 29:

```
Line 27:             DataClasses1DataContext db = new DataClasses1DataContext();
Line 28: 
Line 29:             var UserInfo = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == TextBox1.Text);
Line 30: 
Line 31:             if (UserInfo.Email != null)
```

I'm stumped! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to check for null in the predicate, but if it's a real database it shouldn't be necessary:

```
var UserInfo = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u != null &&
                                            u.Email == TextBox1.Text);
```

But more importantly, there's an obvious error in your code on line 31. If `FirstOrDefault` doesn't find a matching object, it doesn't return an object with all fields set to null. It returns a null reference - i.e. no object at all. You need to test for that:

```
if (UserInfo != null)
{
    Label2.Text = "User found";
}
else
{
    Label2.Text = "User not found";
}
```

In my opinion you should fix the obvious error first, then update your question with the correct code if you are still having problems.

Comment: The exception should come on line 31 in that case

Answer (score 1):

```
var UserInfo = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == TextBox1.Text);
```

You can only get a null ref exception on this line if `db` or `TextBox1` or `TextBox1.Text` is null.  All are doubtful.  I think you have the wrong line.

Comment: What about if `db.Users` or `u` is null? Also `Textbox1.Text` being null shouldn't give an exception. The equality test should just return false.

Comment: u never acquires a value (null or otherwise): it's just a lambda expression parameter that is used to generate an expression tree to generate some sql. db.Users is very unlikely to be null, but I suppose possible.  You are right about Textbox1.Text

Comment: I believe `u` could acquire `null` in LINQ-to-Objects.  The question mentions a "table", suggesting LINQ-to-SQL, but worth mentioning since this distinction can be tricky.

Comment: The code in the question says "DataContext". The question is also tagged [tag:linq-to-sql]. Putting LinqToObjects information in here would be confusing.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var UserInfo = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(u.Email) && u.Email == TextBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

Beside, you can use

```
db.Users.Any(u=> u.Email!=null && u.Email == TextBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Check you code
var UserInfo = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Email == TextBox1.Text);

if (UserInfo.Email != null) // it is wrong
```

first of all you have to check whether UserInfo is null then try to check it's members, like this:

```
if(UserInfo != null)
{
// your code
}
```

It will solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

you should also null check for "UserInfo" too....

try this

**if (UserInfo != null && UserInfo.Email != null)**

```
        {
            Label2.Text = "Email is not null";
        }
        else
        {
            Label2.Text = "Email is null";
        }
```