# Traversing through Linq Result gives Object Reference Not Set to Instance

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, object, linq-to-sql

From my research I noticed my issue was very close to the one found here but yet it still wasn't answering my question for my specific example.

[No result in LINQ query gives Object reference not set to an instance of an object in IF ELSE statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2250229/no-result-in-linq-query-gives-object-reference-not-set-to-an-instance-of-an-obje)

My Linq Query:

```
    var MyResults = (from m in GetData.myTable
            where m.id.equals(123)
            select new 
           {
                value1,
                value2,
                value3
           }).SingleOrDefault();
```

Any of the three fields within value1, value, or value3 can be null.

I check if MyResults is null first (meaning all values were null).

```
if (MyResults != null) 
{
 //  ok lets pretend in this case the values returned in the MyResults were value1 = 3, value2 = null,      value3=null

// now I want to check if each of the values and set desired label
    if (!MyResults.value1.Equals(null))
        {
           label1.text = MyResults.value1;  // 3
        }
    else 
        {
          label1.text = "Null Returned";
        } 

   if (!myResults.value2.equals(null))
       {
        label2.text = MyResults.value2;
       }
   else
       {
        label2.text = "value 2 is null";
       }
       // skipping label3 block here
}
else  // myResults returned null 
{
       label1.text = "All values were null";
}
```

So Label1 is set just fine but when  the code reaches

> if (!MyResults.value2.equals(null))

it throws an error  Object reference not set to an instance of an object, referring to the line **!MyResults.value2.equals(null)** as the culprit.  So how can I go about setting the labels for value 2 and 3 without it crapping out when it processes the null value?

Thanks.  Hopefully someone can teach me what I'm missing.

Comment: If value2 is null, how can you call the Equals method on it?  Have you just tried `if (MyResults.value2 != null)` ?

Comment: @ChrisDunaway this is already an answer not a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem :**  if you have `null` value in any parameter , calling `Equals()` on it throws the above mentioned Exception.(not only `Equals()` , but any function throws exception)

**Solution:** instead of calling `Equals()` method on parameters which you suspect , you need to use `=` operator for checking `null` values.

Try This:

```
   if (myResults.value2 != null)
   {
      label2.Text = MyResults.value2;
   }
```

**Suggestion 1:** You can simplifiy the above code by using conditional statement(ternary operator `?:` )

Try This:

```
if (MyResults != null) 
{
  label1.Text = (MyResults.value1 != null) ? MyResults.value1 : "Null Returned";
  label2.Text = (MyResults.value2 != null) ? MyResults.value2 : "value 2 is null";    
}
else  // myResults returned null 
{
  label1.text = "All values were null";
}
```

**Suggestion 2:** You can also use [null-coalescing operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx) `??` to make it more simple.

From MSDN :

> The ?? operator is called the null-coalescing operator. It returns the
>   left-hand operand if the operand is not null; otherwise it returns the
>   right hand operand.

Try This:

```
if (MyResults != null) 
{
  label1.Text = MyResults.value1 ?? "Null Returned";
  label2.Text = MyResults.value2 ?? "value 2 is null";
}
else
{
  label1.text = "All values were null";
}
```

Comment: Thank you.  I guess I was under the impression that they were equivalent in functionality.  Thanks for educating me and helping me resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it is value2 being null so calling .equals() gives this exception?

Try using

```
if (MyResults.value2 != null)
```

or something. See if it helps.

Comment: Thanks!  As suggested just seconds before you by Sudhakar T your suggestion resolved the issue.  Appreciate the quick response

Answer (score 0):

You can't call `Equals()` on a null reference.  Just do

```
if (MyResults.value2 != null)
```

or

```
if (!Object.ReferenceEquals(MyResults.value2,null))
```